# Inserts taking a lot of time in DB2

Tags: database, triggers, db2, bulkinsert

I have a merge query which on satisfying a condition updates the table, and in case it doesn't satisfy then it inserts the records in another table. The issue is this particular insertion is taking lot of time, around 25 minutes to insert 15,000 records. What I found out is that, while inserting the records, we're also inserting a sequence id, which in turn is generated by a Trigger associated with it. The trigger selects the max id from 2 tables and as such it adds 1 to the max and returns it, which is then used by the Insert query.
Is this the exact reason why Inserts are slower in my Stored Procedure? This SP, runs on DB2.

Comment: Likely the process is using row-by row processing. Look to see if you can find a set-based solution.

Comment: Looking at the query plan will tell you exactly what is the bottleneck. Generating sequence numbers the way you do is generally A Very Bad Idea™, not just because of poor performance, but also because of a possible race condition.

Comment: If DB is maintaining two indexes on the table bluk inserts will take twice as long.  50 indexes will take 50 times as long.  Some OS let you turn off non unique indexes until the index is actually needed.  Or The tables you get the ID from need a unique index on the ID.  Me I would reserve 30k ids and have the job done faster than you can waste ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers are not good solution for performance. Use autoincrement column on your table.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck was indeed the Trigger. I dropped the trigger and ran the sp, it took at most 2 minutes to insert around 15k records. I am using a sequence instead of trigger now.